# Can a CSS only tooltip respond to the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a CSS only tooltip that is also responsive to the viewport. I have found multiple solutions including [this one](https://chrisbracco.com/a-simple-css-tooltip/) by Chris Bracco.

I'm not aware of any way to style the `:before` and `:after` selectors so that they are responsive to the viewport and can adjust their position as a result. Here is a Codepen with a fork from Chris's solution that includes a tooltip that gets cut off: https://codepen.io/anthonytkim/pen/ZyvJbR